# Simply expanding a recyclerview to show a TextView

Tags: java, android

I've explored many ways to achieve this. But I'm much confused now. I tried many Githubs libraries but got confused. Also tried this but I don't think it allows a textview to be shown in expanded view: http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

WHAT I WANT: A simple Recyclerview fetching some text from server for different items. On each item click, a layout or view should be expanded and TextView should become visible with respective fetched text from the server.

I have a simple RecyclerView with code following:

DataAdapter.java

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<List> android_versions;
    private Context context;
    int i =0;

public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<List> android_versions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.android_versions = android_versions;
}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.tv_android.setText(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_version_name());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android_versions.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_android;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tv_android = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
    }
}
```

List.java (Some functions aren't being used as of now)

```
public class List {

    private String android_version_name;
    private String descr;
    private int android_image_url;
    private String android_image_url1;
    public String getAndroid_version_name() {
        return android_version_name;
    }

    public String getDescr(){ return descr;}

    public void setDescr(String descr) {
        this.descr = descr;
    }
    public void setAndroid_version_name(String android_version_name) {
        this.android_version_name = android_version_name;
    }

    public int getAndroid_image_url() {
        return android_image_url;
    }
    public String getAndroid_image_url1() {
        return android_image_url1;
    }

    public void setAndroid_image_url(int android_image_url) {
        this.android_image_url = android_image_url;
    }
    public void setAndroid_image_url1(String android_image_url1) {
        this.android_image_url1 = android_image_url1;
    }
}
```

row_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:translationZ="3dp"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:focusable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_bg">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_android"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Work.java (It's a fragment)

```
String[] sublist={
            "English",
            "Hindi"
    };

  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        rcl = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.homeworklist);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rcl.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>(prepareData()));
        rcl.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public ArrayList prepareData(){
        ArrayList android_version = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<sublist.length;i++){
            List androidVersion = new List();
            androidVersion.setAndroid_version_name(sublist[i]);
            android_version.add(androidVersion);
            break;
        }
        return android_version;
    }
```

Comment: My be just animate text view height from 0 to content height when user click on row item?

Comment: Not possible to place a TextView after each row item

Comment: But  you can place text view into each row item with 0 height, is not?

Comment: Oh yes, I would like to know the best way to achieve this. I will try this. Thanks